# Write and close BufferedWriter in single line code snippet

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter, writer

I've below code snippet.

```
Map<String, Object> globalMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
File talendLogFile = new File("C:\\Softwares\\logFiles\\error.log");
Writer talendLogFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(talendLogFile, true)));

globalMap.put("Logger", talendLogFileWriter);

((BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")).write("I'm Writing");
((BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")).close();
```

Is there any way I could perform both functionalities happening in last two lines in single line of code? I mean close `BufferedWriter` just after write.

Comment: *Is there any way I could perform both functionalities happening in last two lines in single line of code?*  **WHY?!?!**  What does stuffing everything into a single line do?  Well, other than making it **harder** to understand, debug, and maintain...

Comment: @AndrewHenle The real strange part here is: why put something into global map when you afterwards *keep* it in there, but in a state that makes it unusable for *others*?!

Comment: @GhostCat  That too. The implicit "fewer lines of code are better, and one line of code is best!" premise of the question is so misguided that I didn't even reach the specifics of what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using try-with-resources, the real answer is: do **not** do it this way.

You see, you put a writer into a global map. That makes it available to the "whole" world that has access to that map. And next, *some* code intends to close the writer you added to that map.

But it seems that the writer itself is *staying* in the map. So other code can notice: the map has a logger/writer ... but how is that other code supposed to know if that logger/writer is still open, or was closed?

Having a logger/writer in that global map, but it can't be used globally, that is a contradiction in itself!

In other words: conceptually, what you are doing seems wrong. Either you add such a logger/writer to a global map, then **all** code that has access to that map should be able to use that logger/writer (without worrying "is it still open?"). Or, you do **not** put the logger/writer in such a global map.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, yes:

```
((BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")).write("I'm Writing"); ((BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")).close();
```

If you mean use a single method call to do both things, not unless you define a new method to do so.

Comment: How is this a single ?

Comment: How is it not a single line?

Comment: Because all you have done is remove new line. Any formatter will convert it to two lines

Comment: Exactly. Removing a newline makes it into one line. I am not saying it is useful, but it is literally what you asked for. Did you want to ask for a single _statement_, or a single _method call_? Programmers should be precise, computers don't suffer ambiguity well. (I also can't guess your intention since leaving a closed file in a map is not particularly useful, either.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `try-catch with resources`. That mean resources will be automatically closed after `try block` will be done. You can read more here https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources

```
try(Writer talendLogFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(talendLogFile, true)))) {

    globalMap.put("Logger", talendLogFileWriter);

    ((BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")).write("I'm Writing");

}catch(Exception ignored){} //handle the exception if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is this, but as already mentiond by many others, there is no need to. It just complicates things:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = (BufferedWriter) globalMap.get("Logger")) {
    bw.write("I'm Writing");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try with resources which automatically closes the resource without needing to explicitly close it.